# SQLite - getDatabase called recursively

Tags: android, sqlite, getwritabledatabase

Here is my code:

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("sql-query");

        try {
            //db = getWritableDatabase();
            fillAllDB(db);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
// some code
}
```

`fillAllDB(db);` method adds a record to the table, but I can't use `db = getWritableDatabase();` before method call - this is causing the looping. What to do in this case?

Answer (score 2):

`OnCreate` method gives you writable database only, so no need to get the writable database, when you call the writable/readable database, sqlite framework checks whether database exist or not, if not then it will call the `onCreate` method, that why this is recursive, you should not call `getWritable/getReadable` database in `onCreate/onUpgrade` method of the `SqliteOpenHelper` class

Answer (score 1):

Use the `SQLiteDatabase db` argument passed to your `onCreate()` method as the database to call your operations on.

`getWritableDatabase()` and `getReadableDatabase()` will invoke your `onCreate()` in case the database file did not exist, and calling `get...Database()` recursively while the previous call is still being processed causes this exception.

Also, catching exceptions in `onCreate()` is not a good idea. If there's a problem, the `onCreate()` method should not return normally - that tells the framework that the database setup was successful.